# LSTM logits and labels must have the same first dimension (batch_size multiplying by the max_length)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm making an LSTM, and the **batch_size is 32**, the problem is that in the code the batch_size multiplies with the max_length instead of becoming a list. The max length is 19

**I'm sure that it has something to do with the Embedding layer**

---

`print(max_length)` is 19, and that multiples with the batch size instead of becoming a list. I'm looking for it to become [32, 19] so that it could go with the logbits [32, 4040].

> Instead it becomes [608], which is a result of (32 * 19)

Below is the whole code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

dataFile = pd.read_csv("data/Conversation.csv")

questions = dataFile["question"].values
answers = dataFile["answer"].values

max_length = max(max(len(quesiton.split()), len(answer.split())) for quesiton, answer in zip(questions, answers))

vocab = set()

for question, answer in zip(questions, answers):
    vocab.update(question.split())
    vocab.update(answer.split())

word_int = {word: i + 1 for i,word in enumerate(vocab)}

question_seq = [[word_int[word]for word in question.split()] for question in questions]
answer_seq = [[word_int[word] for word in answer.split()] for answer in answers]

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Embedding, Activation
from keras.utils import pad_sequences, to_categorical

question_seq = pad_sequences(question_seq, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
answer_seq = pad_sequences(answer_seq,maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(question_seq, answer_seq, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
voc_size = len(word_int) + 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(voc_size, 100, input_length=max_length))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(voc_size))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['acc'])

print(X_train)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=32)
```

I haven't been able to come up with an idea to how to solve this, here is the error so you can see that the batch and max_length combine

```
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,4040] and labels shape [608]
```

Expected - [32, 19]

Got - [608]